# How do I solve non manifold errors with this relatively simple shape?

Tags: modeling

I'm pretty new to Blender, and I have a model that I am having problems with. I have some non-manifold geometry but I don't know what's wrong. I highlight the edges but I don't see anything wrong with the edges the pointed out. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Non Manifold Edges]

I've tried deleting the edges, because I thought they might be duplicate, but they're not. I tried deleting the surrounding faces and regenerating the faces manually, but that doesn't help. I created this model with a face I subdivided, then extruded the nine faces. Then I cleaned it up and added a bunch of vertices and faces. I thought maybe that construction technique was bad, so I tried creating this same thing by starting with two cubes and repeatedly boolean subtracting the "carving" cube away from the main form. But after four or so cuts I started getting non manifold errors with this technique as well. Any ideas? If you tell me how to export just this object, I can do that and share it if that would help. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Okay, here is the file if anyone wants to look:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2g00zfgs5xyzdhd/non_manifold.blend?dl=0

Inspecting the mesh, I couldn't find the problems you guys mentioned. Maybe I just don't know Blender well enough to see them.

As to **Make Manifold**, I never saw that button there, LOL. It actually works, which is great. Thanks!

I will still be playing around with the mesh as a learning experience however. I want to figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Are there any faces on interior sections (inside the model)?

Comment: if you want to be sure, that people who wanna help you, don't have to guess what's wrong, you should upload your blend file

Comment: Okay, I edited my post with the Blender file. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would stick with the extrusion method, personally, but you do have to be aware of doubled edges or faces, depending on how you extruded it.  I would look at it in Wireframe mode to see if you have anything like this:

[image]

The red arrow is showing a doubled-up face inside the object, so you'd want to delete any of those.

The blue arrow is showing an edge that is ACTUALLY a face (with zero height).

Have you tried simply doing a Merge By Distance to clean up any vertices that are doubled up, or just realllly close to each other?

Also, silly question, but have you tried clicking that "Make Manifold" button there on the right side?

If nothing helps, you could upload the blend file.  If you don't want to upload it because there are other objects in the scene, you could save a copy and delete everything else.

Comment: Ha, I didn't actually see the **Make Manifold** button there. My newness to Blender caught me out I guess. It works, thanks. I'm still going to inspect the mesh, though, to see where I can find the problems. It's a puzzle for me. I'm pretty certain I took care of all the faces like the red arrow ones. I'm going to look for the blue arrow ones and see.

Comment: Okay, I've taken your suggestion and looked at the vertices, and I think that this is the problem. Several of the vertices are doubled up. I'm merging them and recreating the faces, we'll see how that works. Thanks!

Comment: Small update: I was trying to fix the stuff manually, and while I was making progress, stuff I thought I fixed still had some errors in it. So I tried the **Merge by Distance** thing and that fixed almost all the issues. I had one triple-edge left. Thanks so much for your help!